# put in bottom horizontal repeating background without ruining layout

Tags: css

after many hours and starting from similar layout that already worked I have almost managed to get this site working.

My only issue now though is that I can't get a background at the bottom of the page to work without ruining the 100% height.

http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/zen-creations/

The image I want at the bottom is this one: http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/zen-creations/images/page-bkg-bottom.jpg

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with the layout - can you expand a little on exactly what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Ahem. Would you care to explain with some more detail, which background you're talking about? Your page looks like it's fixed up real nice...

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't in enough detail. Basically I'm try to put in a repeating background horizontally across the bottom of the page without messing up the current layout.

I've got a footer fixed to the bottom of the browser which moves down with if the content exceeds the height of the browser window.

Here's a little temporary video explaining what I'm on about - http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/jing/css-layout.swf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulled footer out of container

```
<div id="container">
    …
</div>
<div id="footerContainer">
    <div id="footer">
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

Added CSS

```
div#footerContainer {
    position:relative; /* needed for centering */
    background:url(../images/page-bkg-bottom.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
}

div#footer {
    width:1120px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url(../images/footer.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
    height:459px;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
```

I hate this solution, you've now got the width specified in two places. When is CSS coming up with variables?

---

I quite like this one, but it screws up if one makes the window smaller.

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/page-bkg-top.jpg'), /* not sure if \n works */
                     url('images/page-bkg-bottom.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top left, bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks GS, much appreciated :). I tried both your solutions though and could not get either of them to work :(.

I'll try again tomorrow but thanks anyway...

Comment: The file I used: http://www.easy-share.com/1907988256/zen%20homepage.zip (worked in Safari 4)

Comment: One million thank you's GS, you are a legend! I'll buy you a beer or two if you are ever in Ballina, Australia.

Thanks again :)

Comment: That's about the remotest place from where I live.